# How to combine dates of trips of the person?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, dictionary, if-statement

Could you please help me? I've got an algorithm which is supposed to find the arrival date and departure date of the nearest trips of the person.
Here it is:

```
trips = dict()
countries = dict()
passengers = dict()

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    party_rk, passenger, created_dt, arrival_dt, departure_dt, country_cd = row
    
    # if the person doesn't have any trips then add the first one
    if trips.get(party_rk, 'Empty') == 'Empty':
        trips[party_rk] = []
        trips[party_rk].append([created_dt, arrival_dt, departure_dt])

        countries[party_rk] = []
        countries[party_rk].append(set(country_cd))
        
        passengers[party_rk] = []
        passengers[party_rk].append(set([tuple(passenger)]))
        
    else:
        trips_by_party = trips[party_rk]
        end_last_trip = trips_by_party[-1][1]
        previous_country_cd = countries[party_rk][-1]
        
        if (country_cd == 'RUS' and previous_country_cd == 'RUS') or (country_cd != 'RUS' and previous_country_cd != 'RUS'):
            # if the next trip starts earlier or just after the last one then combine them
            if arrival_dt <= end_last_trip + datetime.timedelta(days=1):
                trips[party_rk][-1][1] = max(end_last_trip, departure_dt)
                countries[party_rk][-1].update(set(country_cd))
                add_person(passengers[party_rk][-1], passenger)
    
            # add new period of the trip
            else:
                trips[party_rk].append([created_dt, arrival_dt, departure_dt])
                countries[party_rk].append(set(country_cd))
                passengers[party_rk].append(set([tuple(passenger)]))
        else:
            trips[party_rk].append([created_dt, arrival_dt, departure_dt])
            countries[party_rk].append(set(country_cd))
            passengers[party_rk].append(set([tuple(passenger)]))
```

And here is the example:

[image]

It's supposed to be like that:

- 1 trip: 2023-11-04 - 2023-11-11
- 2 trip: 2024-04-13 - 2024-04-20

The main idea is to combine the trips which are close to each other and separate them from the trips which are far later than the previous ones.

Comment: Is there a respect in which the code is not working? The input data in the screen dump doesn't show the "party" or destination, so there's no reason to think that the collated data doesn't match what's expected.

Comment: oh, yes, I'm sorry. now I've just added a more appropriate example